# Laravel - Order by as Number (int), even if column type is string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

here it is:-

```
$query = Section::orderBy("section", "desc")->get();
```

section here is a column with type string yet it is having numbers in it where i want to order by those numbers
thanks for your response

Comment: Why have a column where you store numbers and make it a string? Just create a migration where you update the column to be a integer and then you can order by number easier.

Comment: It should work in mysql or pg. 
What result do you get?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can use [orderByRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods) with [mysql convert](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp)

```
$query = Section::orderByRaw('CONVERT(section, SIGNED) desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

*First you should use proper data types while designing schema.*

For your existing schema you can tweak your order by clause to type cast your value at runtime using `orderByRaw` method

```
->orderByRaw('section * 1 desc')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$query->orderByRaw("section::int", "desc")->get();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would help OP and future readers more if you explain *why* and *how*

Comment: It's important to add that this only works with a full query, if you want to paginate or continue to tweek your query this won't work as intended.