MySQL: Sort columns in descending string type in LARAVEL
How can I sort the values ​​of a string column by number in descending order? use ORM laravel
For example:
| id | misc |
| 1   | BH-2   |
| 2   | BH-4   |
| 3   | BH-1   |
| 4   | BH-3   |

Expect results
| id | misc |
| 3   | BH-1   |
| 1   | BH-2   |
| 4   | BH-3   |
| 2   | BH-4   |

Looking forward to receiving everyone's answers. thanks all !

What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Are you looking for raw SQL or ORM code?

I don't have any plans for myself yet! i wish to get answer from laravel ORM ! can you help me ?

Well if I was you I would google your question title before posting it, because it appears to have been answered before e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63354896/laravel-order-by-as-number-int-even-if-column-type-is-string

I just tried these but it doesn't seem to work because it doesn't have the text "BH-"

So strip that text off?

Actually I don't know how to do it, my laravel knowledge is a bit poor

Sure, but it's been done a hundred times before, just google it .

ORDER BY 0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '-', -1)

or use : ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE(misc, '[A-Za-z- ]', '')

Poor sample data, add BH-10.

Use regex: \d+$ to trim digits from misc field.
So, MySQL query is:
select *
from TBL_INFO
ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(misc, '\\d+$', 1, 0) AS SIGNED INTEGER)

Output:
id  misc
3   BH-1
1   BH-2
4   BH-3
2   BH-4

Sample Code: db<>fiddle

